# UI-databinding -- is rendering done step by step in ember?

Tags: performance, user-interface, data-binding, ember.js

## Background

#### A lot of my UI is databound, to the model of the controller.

I wanna make more then one change and then let the visual changes to the databinding happen, not step by step. Like a transaction, not causing step by step updates to the UI.

## Question 1

#### Will UI-databinding trigger step-by-step when makin changes within setupController?

```
setupController:  function( controller, model ) {
    var manager = controller.get('manager');
    controller.set('model', model); // Will databound UI evaluate NOW?

    if (manager)
        manager.reset();
    else
        controller.set('manager', App.WorkManager.create());

    // Or will the databound UI evaluate after this full function has run?
},
```

## Question 2

#### If so, is there such a thing as suspendRendering() / resumeRendering()? (A way to suspend such step-by-step changes, and make them add up until you resume?)

```
setupController:  function( controller, model ) {
    var manager = controller.get('manager');
    // Best solution would be - Part 1
    // ????.suspendRendering();
    controller.set('model', model); 

    if (manager)
        manager.reset();
    else
        controller.set('manager', App.WorkManager.create());

    // Best solution would be - Part 2
    // ????.resumeRendering();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is tied up in Ember's run loop. There's a really great explanation of it [here](http://alexmatchneer.com/blog/2013/01/12/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-the-ember-run-loop/). Basically, the run loop is responsible for making sure that all computed properties bindings and observers have a chance to fire before any changed values are ultimately rendered to the DOM. I believe route transitions happen within the context of a run loop. So, any code that is executed inside `setupController` will execute fully before UI rendering takes place.